# trying to sql theory: iterating over find nth max to sort (your order by function is broken) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, theory

I come from a more imperative coding background so some declarative implementations are not quite that natural yet. My question is in the hypothetical scenario where you don't have access to by order by function but have a set of values and (and monotonically increasing by 1) rownumbers and want a sorted return.

conceptually it seems like a cross join and having mask or a correlated subquery should work but I haven't been able to flush it out yet and looking for some guidance.

Conceptually iterating over nth high value in correlated subquery should work but I'm not sure how to get it to run for each row.

```
select a.name, a.value
from table a 
where a.row_number = select(count(*) 
                         from table b 
                         where b.value < a.value)
```

the other idea i had was to use a cross join and but it seems like a correlated subquery makes more sense, any thoughts or links to resources would be great. thanks

Sample data

|id| value|

|1 | 12   |

|2 | 4    |

|3 | 13   |

|4 | 9    |

Output

|value|

4

9

12

13

Comment: Why not just use the LIMIT clause?

Comment: You can iterate using a subquery with a join. But if you want to get a sorted return, you need to use `ORDER BY` in the subquery. If you can't use `ORDER BY`, I think you're out of luck if you have to use pure SQL.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you want to do.  That is why sample data and desired results are so helpful.

Comment: sample data added thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GeorgeGreen You might be able to ask this question on cs.stackexchange.com. The basic question is: How can I order results of a pure SQL query without using ORDER BY?

Comment: Thanks @Patrick87, I actually think I figured it out without a subquery or a cross join but just with a self join, where the row number table is a temporary table, then select a.value, count(*) from joining on a.value>= b.value and grouping by a.value and left joining the row number from the temp table to the count from the joined table creates the rank of the value and maintains the order via the row_number implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this is your question:

> you don't have access to by order by function but have a set of values
>   and (and monotonically increasing by 1) rownumbers and want a sorted
>   return.

You are missing a really important point about SQL:  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  A result set is *unordered* unless you explicitly specify the ordering using `ORDER BY`.

Subqueries -- correlated or otherwise -- do not affect ordering in any consistent and dependable way.  If you want "a sorted return" you have to use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, however, and not to be rude, saying use order by when I'm specifically trying to understand how operations are executed in mysql is not particularly helpful. Without the row_number this clearly does not make any sense however my goal is try and use this additional piece of information to get the execution i desire.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen Yes, but this is like asking for the Nth item in a hashtable.  That's why it's a strange question.  It's a non-deterministic result, and SQL is about being deterministic.  If you're basing it off of some arbitrary row numbering, you can execute the same query against an identical table and -- without `ORDER BY` -- get different results and that's *still correct*.  SQL is about writing queries that *don't* do that.